# Is this a good alternative of asyncio.sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, sleep

I decided not use `asyncio.sleep()` and tried to create my own coroutine function as shown below. Since, `time.sleep` is an IO bound function, I thought this will print 7 seconds. But it prints 11 seconds.

```py
import time
import asyncio


async def my_sleep(delay):
    time.sleep(delay)

async def main():
    start = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(my_sleep(4), my_sleep(7))
    print("Took", time.time()-start, "seconds")

asyncio.run(main())

# Expected: Took 7 seconds
# Got: Took 11.011508464813232 seconds
```

Though if I write a similar code with threads, It does print 7 seconds. Do `Task` objects created by `asyncio.gather` not recognize `time.sleep` as an IO bound operation, the way threads do? Please explain why is it happening.

Comment: The event loop can only yield to another task anytime you `await` something. Your `my_sleep` doesn't `await` anything, so doesn’t yield execution, so nothing can run in parallel. (And no, `await`ing `time.sleep` doesn’t do anything, as it’s not an async function.)

Comment: Why did you not want to use asyncio.sleep?

Answer (score 3):

`time.sleep` is blocking operation for event loop. It has no sense if you write `async` in defention of function because it not unlock the event loop (no `await` command)

This two questions might help you to understand more:

[Python 3.7 - asyncio.sleep() and time.sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729764/python-3-7-asyncio-sleep-and-time-sleep)

[Run blocking and unblocking tasks together with asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63704156/run-blocking-and-unblocking-tasks-together-with-asyncio)

Answer (score 1):

This would not work for you because `time.sleep` is a *synchronous* function.

From the 'perspective' of the event loop `my_sleep` might as well be doing a heavy computation within an async function, never yielding the execution context while working.

The first tell tale sign of this is that you're not using an `await` statement when calling `time.sleep`.

Making a synchronous function behave as an async one is not trivial, but the common approach is moving the function call to worker threads and awaiting the results.
I'd recommend looking at the solution of [anyio](https://github.com/agronholm/anyio/blob/07b49f76597f353185c825e2acd1b1b9fe274727/src/anyio/to_thread.py#L10), they implemented a `run_sync` function which does exactly that.